# Вызов функции класса

Tags: php, ооп

Как сделать загрузку функций более простой и быстрой?
Необходим такой результат:

```
AdminController::actionIndex();
```

Если таких action будет много проблематично подключить каждую функцию.
Не могу сообразить как сделать что-то подобное, чтобы работало  
`AdminController::{action}{имя Action(например actionIndex, actionLogin)}`

Comment: что за мода делать контроллеры и экшены статическими?

Comment: а как это будет работать с $this?

Comment: со статическими проще работать

Comment: `Данный подход видел в Yii2` - где там такое есть? исключая `Yii::$app`, который ни разу не контроллер?

Comment: `со статическими проще работать` - в чем состоит удобство? вместо `obj->action` писать `class::action`? В чем профит?

Comment: я не совсем понял желаемый результат какой. Можно сделать `$action = "actionIndex";` и вызывать `AdminController::$action();` это то что надо?

Comment: так оно не работает -- Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in...

Comment: @paqstd ты что-то не так делаешь http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/851b49279a902abe08a97521face59ac3bfe0c6d ..... либо версия PHP древняя

Comment: В целом тебе нужны http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php  и    http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php  ...... а вообще неплохо было бы поставить адекватную IDE и просто покопаться во внутренностях того самого тобой упомянутого *Yii2* и посмотреть что у них имеется на сий счет. Благо в IDE можно перейти в любой метод любого класса мгновенно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$action = 'index';
$controller = 'admin';

if(method_exist(ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller', 'action' . ucfirst($action))) {
   call_user_func([
       cfirst($controller) . 'Controller', 
       'action' . ucfirst($action)
   ]);
} else {
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
   echo 'Не найдена';
}
```

Где то так определяем по url какой controller и action запрашивается, смотрим есть ли метод и вызываем.

Comment: вам бы опечатки исправить в коде

Comment: Небольшие опечатки, но в целом спасибо! Перед контроллером еще нужно namespace писать

Comment: @teran покажи где плиз

Comment: в `cal_user_func`? :)

Comment: @teran ok увидел :) спс